# Cycles Textures and the Displace Modifier

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, displacement

I've been working on a procedural texture with the intention of using it in the Displace Modifier, but I've been doing it in a Cycles Shader tree, (simply using an Emission shader to display it).

In the end, I want access to the physically displaced mesh for 3D printing, so Cycles displacement at render-time won't do.. Do I have to reconstruct the relevant Cycles nodes as a Blender Texture? Or can I bake the Cycles renderer's displacement into the mesh?

At the risk of asking two questions, what will happen to the Displace Modifier when the Blender Internal Renderer goes? Will Blender's internal texture system go, too?

Comment: It won't be needed to reconstruct the tree if you bake the node tree result on the object and add texture to Displacement modifier - but it won't be procedural any more.